# Eigenvalues of a partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, wave-equation, eigenfunctions

[image]

Why $\lambda_n=sgn(n)\pi i \sqrt{n^2+\alpha}$?

I have this:

$\varphi_{xx}-(\alpha+\lambda^2)\varphi=0$ and $\varphi(0)=\varphi(1)=0$ then $\varphi(x)=c\sin(\sqrt{-(\alpha+\lambda^2)}x)+d\cos(\sqrt{-(\alpha+\lambda^2)}x)$, and $d=0$ then $\varphi(x)=c\sin(\sqrt{-(\alpha+\lambda^2)}x)$ and $0=\sin(\sqrt{-(\alpha+\lambda^2)}) \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{-(\alpha+\lambda^2)}=n\pi$

$\sqrt{-(\alpha+\lambda^2)}=n\pi\Rightarrow \lambda_n=sgn(n)\pi i \sqrt{n^2+\alpha}$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think there's a mistake in the text. The equation follows that $ \lambda = i\sqrt{(n\pi)^2+\alpha} $. What is $A$?

Comment: $\phi=(\varphi,z)$ with $z=\varphi'$
$\phi'+A\phi=0$ and $\phi(0)=\phi^0$ (abstract form Cauchy)
$A(\varphi,z)=(-z,-{\partial}_{x}^{2}+\alpha \varphi)$
$A$ is differential operator